# How to resize buttons with gradient background?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have some problems with button background when try to resize it, I use autoresize and 5.5 inch iPhone screen in interface builder. On iPhone 6plus and 6s plus buttons looks great like in interface builder but in 6 and 5s i see that buttons background width on 4 and 4.7 inch screen equal button background in interface builder. But when i press button it redraw and looks correct as i want(second screenshot). Here is screenshots. How can i fix it?

[image: first screenshot] [image]

Here is my code which locate in viewDidLoad

```
//** Gradient for red buttons **\\

    colorsForRedButtonGradient = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                  (id)[UIColor colorWithRed:139.0/255.0 green:2.0/255.0 blue:2.0/255.0 alpha:1.0].CGColor,
                                  (id)[UIColor colorWithRed:155.0/255.0 green:21.0/255.0 blue:21.0/255.0 alpha:1.0].CGColor,
                                  nil];
    highlightedColorsForRedButtonGradient = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                             (id)[UIColor colorWithRed:139.0/255.0 green:2.0/255.0 blue:2.0/255.0 alpha:0.5].CGColor,
                                             (id)[UIColor colorWithRed:155.0/255.0 green:21.0/255.0 blue:21.0/255.0 alpha:1.0].CGColor,
                                             nil];

    NSArray *locationForRedButtonGradient = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                             [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0f],
                                             [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0f],
                                             nil];

    gradientLayerForSoundButton = [CAGradientLayer layer];
    gradientLayerForPopupButton = [CAGradientLayer layer];
    gradientLayerForVibroButton = [CAGradientLayer layer];

    gradientLayerForVibroButton.frame = _vibroButton.layer.bounds;
    gradientLayerForSoundButton.frame = _soundButton.layer.bounds;
    gradientLayerForPopupButton.frame = _popupButton.layer.bounds;

    gradientLayerForVibroButton.colors = colorsForRedButtonGradient;
    gradientLayerForVibroButton.locations = locationForRedButtonGradient;
    gradientLayerForSoundButton.colors = colorsForRedButtonGradient;
    gradientLayerForSoundButton.locations = locationForRedButtonGradient;
    gradientLayerForPopupButton.colors = colorsForRedButtonGradient;
    gradientLayerForPopupButton.locations = locationForRedButtonGradient;

    gradientLayerForVibroButton.cornerRadius = _vibroButton.layer.cornerRadius;
    [_vibroButton.layer insertSublayer:gradientLayerForVibroButton atIndex:0];
    gradientLayerForSoundButton.cornerRadius = _soundButton.layer.cornerRadius;
    [_soundButton.layer insertSublayer:gradientLayerForSoundButton atIndex:0];
    gradientLayerForPopupButton.cornerRadius = _popupButton.layer.cornerRadius;
    [_popupButton.layer insertSublayer:gradientLayerForPopupButton atIndex:0];
```

Comment: Instead of `viewDidLoad` write it in `viewDidAppear` because after the view is appeared in the `UI` it use to have the actual frame sizes in auto layout. As you are doing in `viewDidLoad` so it is taking the frames of the component size you have created in your xibs or storyboard.

Comment: i add it in viewDidAppear and it looks great!! Thanks you man!

Answer (score 0):

It's looking like, you have given a static width to all buttons. You need to place all buttons in a view and set their leading & trailing constraints.

You can also  set min-max width to all buttons to take over control on the width for different devices or you can also specify a minimum and maximum width to view in your viewcontroller.

So, this can be solution for your problem.

Regards

-vikas.